# Solving geodesic problems with Euler-Lagrange equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, geodesy

This is the question:

Problem B.1 Two cities - Tel-Aviv, Israel and SanDiego, CA - have the same latitude 32
◦ N, but, diﬀerent
longitudes: Tel-Aviv is 34
◦
E and San-Diego is 117
◦ W.
What is the maximal distance between the great circle arc
and the 32
◦
latitude line? By how much the path along
the great circle (geodesic) arc will be shorter than the path along the
latitude line? Hint: Spherical triangles (on a sphere with
radius 1) satisfy a spherical law of cosines $$\cos(c)=\cos(a)\cos(b)+\sin(a)\sin(b)\cos(C)$$.

I don't want the solution. My main problem is I don't know where to begin and where I want to get to. Could you help me with figuring out how to get through such problems?

Euler-Lagrange equation:
$$\frac{d}{dx}L_{y'}-L_y=0$$ while $$I[y(x)]=\int_{x_0}^{x_1}L(y',y,x)dx$$

Full description (as our lecturer assures us) is right [here](http://www.ph.biu.ac.il/data/teach/l/86-207/mathematical_physics_2011.pdf), page 2.

Comment: Can you write the Euler-Lagrange equations for the length function?

Comment: @AlexanderNikolasGruber I had edited the post.

Comment: Is a 'latitude line' a straight line between the two cities? And if so, why bother with Euler Lagrange to solve the problem?

Comment: @copper.hat Yes. But the question is what is the maximal distance between geodesic and latitude lines.

Comment: If I understand correctly, the geodesic, the latitude line and center of the earth all lie on the same 2-dim. plane. The end points of the geodesic define an angle $\alpha$ in this plane, the maximum separation will occur at $\frac{\alpha}{2}$, etc, etc...

Comment: @copper.hat The geodesic lies on the same plane as earth center, but the latitude slices the sphere parallel to equator. Logically, it is clear that the distance is maximal at $\frac{\alpha}{2}$, but it needs to be proved. If I'm not that clear - you could check out the link in the post. There's the full explanation.